# progressbar color changes all progress dialog colors

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I used the code below to change color of progressbar and its working but its changing `all` theprogressbars within different `progressdialogs` in that `ACTIVITY` only but WHy is it changing the color of all progressbar dialog even though I have assigned progressbar with exact android id and I want `only` that `progressbar` color to be changed and not all. I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.:

My code :

```
ProgressBar spinner;



spinner =(ProgressBar)findviewbyid(R.id.progressbar1);
spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

xml :

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar1
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edittext1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edittext1"
android:paddingTop="14dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip" 
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Did you have any progress with it?

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg check style(custom) if its applied to all progress dialog else create one or else for each activity select style/theme in manifest.

Answer (score -2):

remove `android:visibility = "gone"` or use 
       `android:visibility = "visible"`
I think it should work.

Comment: I have done thaT ALSO but thats not the point .The point is why the color of progressbar within other progressdialog is also changing?

Comment: hello user3154663, I think you are doing well. I am not use this progress dialog but please change this point "android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY" I is working for multipl color. I think it will help And please let me know if it will work.

Comment: what? can you tell me how to change color of particular progressbar `spinner` in the case above without changing color of all the other progressdialog with progressbar